# How can I make sudo never ask for a password with a certain argument, but always ask for a password with another argument?

Tags: linux, macos, sudo

For example, I want to allow `sudo shutdown -c` to always be run without entering a password, but `sudo shutdown` without `-c` to always require a password (even if I've authenticated to `sudo` previously).

Answer (score 1):

To change your sudo configuration you need to edit you /etc/sudoers file by using visudo (Only use this because it has validation included. If you don't know how to use vi [here](http://maeks84.wordpress.com/2008/05/29/how-to-use-visudo/) are the quick basics you need to edit the file). To allow certain parameters there is an answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/167631/fine-grained-sudoers-configuration-allowed-commandline-arguments). So you would basically add something like

```
user ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/shutdown -c
```

to the file to allow all users to excecute `shutdown -c` without entering a password. To make sudo allways ask for a password you can set the timeout to 0 by adding

```
Defaults timestamp_timeout = 0
```

this is not command specific (sorry couldn't find anything better) but will ask for a password for all commands that need one to execute (ie there is no `NOPASSWD` option specified).

For more details on what you can do with your sudoers file see the [official page](http://www.sudo.ws/sudoers.man.html).