# Block linux command with specific argument

Tags: linux, command-line

I want to block certain linux command for root user with only few arguments.
Like "df" command should be blocked with -h argument but should be available for other arguments. I know how to block the whole command to run, but never blocked with such segregation.

Comment: You can't. `root` has total control. Even if you blocked it by say, aliasing `df` through a script, you can work around it by calling the binary.

Comment: By definition, it is impossible to truly restrict what root can do on a \*nix system. You can put obstacles in the way, but any halfway-competent user running as root will be able to get around them. If you don't absolutely trust someone, don't let them run as root.

Comment: It looks like `sudo` could be helpful in your situation. Specifically as was answered [here](http://superuser.com/q/167631/238539). Otherwise it is wrong concept from very beginning of this idea. You give root access or you do not. `TRUE` or `FALSE`. It can not be half way. There is `sudo` for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

One way i can think up of is to use a restricted shell like rbash and place a script *df* in the custom path for that user where the right command is called but this most probably won't work.

Root is powerful guy and unless he is not really root like in the case of rbac/selinux you are not really able to stop him.

Try to look if this can be done but i doubt it.

The other way around is to get the sources, remove the offending option (from the option parser will be enough) and rebuild the binary. This has it's own issues though.

- You lose the package management
- You can very easily create security holes like this

Comment: Here is what I have used to block apt-get on Ubuntu machine in .bashrc:  

`/usr/bin/apt-get() {  
  echo "This command not allow for you"  
}  
apt-get() {  
  echo "This command not allow for you"  
}  
./apt-get() {  
  echo "This command not allow for you"  
}`  

I want users not to run "apt-get update" but they can use apt-get to install any package. Above will completely block apt-get command.

Comment: Isn't polkit doing the same in gnome?

and secondly why for the love of god you want the users to be able to use administrative commands. If you are giving out root passwords ... there is something wrong with your administration model.

Comment: This is not a production system, but a testing system. Users here have root privileges but they do not know much about the system. I do not want them to use "apt-get update" (centos upgrades its version with this) but they can use apt-get for installing packages.

Comment: Centos does not use apt-get but rpm/yum. If you would like to mask that it is rpm then by all means write a wrapper script name it apt-get and let the users run it. If it is a test system make a good solid backup maybe just a hw raid1 with 1 disk removed and let the users play/destroy. I still believe that letting **users** run free around even a test system is not acceptable.

Comment: Sorry for typo. S/b yum. I will try with wrapper script. I dont have control on that system except the configuration part and I dont want them to come to me to re-build the machine.